# "value": this field cannot be set when using aws_ssm_parameter

Tags: terraform

I am trying to define some SSM parameters in AWS (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html).

Here is my related terraform code:

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "team_name" {
  name = "TEST"
  value = var.test
}
```

It throws this error:

```
Error: "value": this field cannot be set

  on myproject.tf line 57, in data "aws_ssm_parameter" "team_name":
  57: data "aws_ssm_parameter" "team_name" {
```

How can I set a value into a SSM parameter store via terraform?

Answer (score 1):

It should have been `resource` instead of `data`

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "team_name" {
```